# Trying to change the color of text on click in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, colors

So I am trying to make something where whenever I click on the text it change's color.

Javascript:

```
function changecolor(){
    var tc = document.getElementById("header").style.color.value;
    if  (tc = "#000000") { tc = "#0009FF"}
    else if (tc == "#0009FF") { tc = "#FF0000"}
    else if (tc == "#FF0000") { tc = "#15FF00"}
    else if (tc == "#15FF00") { tc = "#FFA600"}
    else {tc = "#000000"};
    document.getElementById("header").style.color.value = tc;
}
```

html:

```
<div onclick="changecolor()"><h1 id="header" style="color:#000000;"> Nick's Basic Physic's Calculator </h1></div>
```

It is not working and I have not been able to figure out why. When I click on the text nothing happens.

Comment: Not sure, but I think that problem in your html `onclick="changecolor()"` because I think that on click will be executed result of `changecolor` function, try to change it to `onclick="changecolor"`

Answer (score 1):

Change

`document.getElementById("header").style.color.value = tc;`

to

`document.getElementById("header").style.color = tc;`

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xEyLf/

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in     `var tc = document.getElementById("header").style.color.value;`

you have to change to  `tc = document.getElementById("header").style.color;`in order to get the color into variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution... here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zfJA/

Keep in mind I'm using these jQuery methods (as well as the jQuery library itself), by simply switching between CSS classes:

```
hasClass(): to check if the class is present

addClass(): to add the correct class based on the condition above

removeClass(): remove all classes, I've basically built a "reset" function
```

I think there are errors in the way it functions and how you want it, but I've built it on the same logic you have in your question.